# How to store execution result on entity arbitrarily without effecting gameplay?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I need to store the amount of one item a player has in their inventory to their own entity, but I need to store it in an arbitrary way that doesn't effect the gameplay.
If this makes it any clearer, I want to simply store it on the entity to be accessed later, I don't want to store it to "Score" or something that will change anything in the gameplay.

I know this much:

`/execute as @a store result entity @s ***PATH*** int 1 run clear @s minecraft:netherite_ingot 0`

I don't know what to put in the path to be able to access the data later.

I tried storing it in the entities tags, but I couldn't find any way of accessing specifically the first tag. I searched for an answer, and tried things like `Tags[1]`, `{Tags.[1]}` and `{Tags.1}`

Does anybody know how to store data to an entity in a different, arbitrary way, or how to access specifically the first, second or third tag of an entity?

Comment: Why don't you want to use scores? They're the *easiest* way to attribute numbers to entities.